# What does "linear interpolation" mean?

Tags: wpf

I often hear the term "linear interpolation" in context with animations in WPF. What exactly does "linear interpolation" mean? Could you give me an example where to use "linear interpolation"?

Comment: As to what it means: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Linear means lines (straight ones).

Interpolation is the act of finding a point *within* two other points. Contrast this with extrapolation, which is finding a point beyond the ends of a line.

So linear interpolation is the use of a straight line to find a point between two others.

For example:

```
     *(5,10)
    /
   /
  /
 /
*(0,0)
```

You can use the two endpoints with linear interpolation to get the points along the line:

```
(1,2)
(2,4)
(3,6)
(4,8)
```

and linear *extrapolation* to get (for example):

```
(1000,2000)
(-1e27,-2e27)
```

---

In animation, let's say you have a bouncing ball that travels from the `(x,y)` position of `(60,22)` to `(198,12)` in `10` seconds.

With an animation rate of 10 frames per second, you can calculate it's position at any time with:

```
x0 = 60, y0 = 22
x1 = 198, y1 = 12
frames = 100
for t = 0 to frames:
    x = (x1 - x0) * (t / frames) + x0
    y = (y1 - y0) * (t / frames) + y0
```

Those two formulae at the bottom are examples of linear interpolation. At 50% (where `t == 50`):

```
x = (198 - 60) * (50 / 100) + 60
  =     138    *    0.5     + 60
  =            69           + 60
  =                  129

y = (12 - 22) * (50 / 100) + 22
  =    -10    *    0.5     + 22
  =           -5           + 22
  =                   17
```

and `(129,17)` is the midpoint between the starting and ending positions.

Comment: it may also mean linear in terms of constant rate, so the interpolation does not change rate regardless of where you are.

Comment: I love the explanation, straightforward and easy to understand.

Comment: BRAVOO, this is first time I understand linear interpolation, Nice answer :)

Answer (score 1):

E.g. when you want a storyboard to move an element from one position to another using a fixed speed, then you'd use linear interpolation between the start and end positions.

Comment: if you had a non linear interpolation you could make the element appear to start fast and the slow down as it approached its destination