# Moving circle towards touched point

Tags: java, android, paint, geometry, ontouch

i'm trying to move a circle to the point i touch in my running app. I want to see the circle moving along a path towards this point i touch.

I have three classes:

```
public class Drawing  extends View{
    Context ctx;
static Circle c1;

private float circleCenterX = 100;
private float circleCenterY = 100;

private float lerpX;
private float lerpY;

private float time = 25;

private float frames = 100;

public Drawing(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.ctx = context;
        c1 = new Circle (165, 350, 33);
    }

public void update(float x, float y) {
    this.circleCenterX = x;
    this.circleCenterY = y;
}

protected void onDraw (android.graphics.Canvas canvas){
    Paint p = new Paint();

    p.setColor(Color.GREEN);

    lerpX = (circleCenterX - c1.getX()) * (time / frames) + c1.getX();
    lerpY = (circleCenterY - c1.getY()) * (time / frames) + c1.getY();

    canvas.drawCircle(lerpX, lerpY, c1.getR(), p);

    c1.setX(lerpX);
    c1.setY(lerpY);
}

public class Circle {
private float x;
private float y;
private float r;
public Circle(float x, float y, float r) {
    super();
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = r;
}
public float getX() {
    return x;
}
public void setX(float x) {
    this.x = x;
}
public float getY() {
    return y;
}
public void setY(float y) {
    this.y = y;
}
public float getR() {
    return r;
}
public void setR(float r) {
    this.r = r;
}`
public class Game extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

 Drawing d;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     d=new Drawing(this);

     setContentView(d);
     d.setOnTouchListener(this);
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {

     d.update(me.getX(), me.getY());
     d.invalidate();
     return true;
 }
```

I think i will need something like a while or for loop to increment the x and y coords and or maybe need a speed value?!

Maybe im totally wrong and its a lot of more math to get it.

Thanks for your help

Cheers

Comment: Add a language tag to get more views and help. I'm guessing that you are using [java] + [android]?

Comment: Yes you are right! Which language tag do you mean?

Comment: Never mind. I added the tags to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time `onDraw` is called you need to move the circle a bit. The easiest way is just to move a certain number of pixels each time it's called.

To be able to do this you need to keep track of:

- Where the animation started
- Where you want the animation to end

Use [linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) to calculate the position of the circle in each `onDraw` call

Comment: Thanks, this sound good! I googled it for 2 hours now and didnt find anything workable. I tried to test around with a while-loop like "while(currentY < touchedY && currentX < touched X) { canvas.drawCircle(c1.getX()+1, c1.getY()+1, c1.getR(), p); }"

Comment: The screen is refreshed all the time and `onDraw` is called before drawing. A while loop inside `onDraw` will make the circle arrive at the destination before the circle is ever even drawn on the screen. Also, the code you have there for `drawCircle` will not move it to where you've touched.

Comment: Ok got it, do you have an example for me How to use the linearInterpolator? Tank you!

Comment: I know swiched my approach to moving the circle only 10 pixel to the direction i touched without walking down a specific line. So i just want to move up if the touch was above my current point and so on for up, down, right, left, upright, downright, upleft, downleft. See the update in my codepost!

Comment: My approach is getting easier every day. Im just working on an "up-movement" but it doesnt work correctly like this.

Comment: Ok, forget everything i made. I have got a new solution using a slope. This is working better but still not correct. I dont know what is wrong. Maybe c1.getX() is always looking at the same point and not at the new Circle position. Maybe you guys have any ideas!? Thanks in advance

Comment: Here's a post about linear interpolation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249417/what-does-linear-interpolation-mean
But you can't use a for loop just calculate x and y like they do here each time onDraw is called.

Comment: Yeah Thank you Simon! This looks very good, only thing a dont understand, it seems to me that c1.getX() or .getY() is always refering to one fix point and not the current position of the circle (Maybe initialization location?). Does anyone know how to fix that?

Comment: Solved it now! Many thanks to you Simon! Just forgot to set the x and y value for the new location of the circle after drawing it on the touch position!